# Cannot call value of non-function type '((UIImage!, Success!, Failure!) -> Void)!'

Tags: swift

I'm trying to call a method in a swift file for our library that is written in objective-c and uses blocks.

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '((UIImage!, Success!,
>   Failure!) -> Void)!'

for this code

```
(APIService.instance() as AnyObject).updateAvatar(image, success: { (Any) -> Void in

}) { (error: Error) in

}
```

I normally call the objective-c method like this

```
[[APIService instance] updateAvatar: self.avatarImage success:^(id object) {



} failure:^(NSError *error) {


}];
```

I'm new to swift so it could be something stupid that I'm missing.

Comment: Why are you casting `APIService.instance()` to `AnyObject` in the beginning? Probably need to remove that and just use: `APIService.instance().update....`

Comment: Then it says  Value of type 'Any' has no member 'updateAvatar' and has an auto correct error which when I click on it, it adds the anyObject

Comment: How about trying `APIService.instance() as APIService` assuming instance() returns an API service

Comment: Agree with @Benzi either cast correctly or more relevant: why does `APIService.instance()` return nothing specific?

Comment: the objective c its a block so it should return id as an object in the block but the swift should be any object since id can be anything.